# Slow startup of win-form application on Windows 8 x64

Tags: performance, windows-8, .net-4.0, 64-bit, startup

Ive exhausted my search for answers to this one so I thought Id best ask here. I have a win-form application built on Win7 x64 using VS2010 (vb.net). The application TargetCPU is set to AnyCPU and uses .net4 client profile. The application runs fine on all Windows versions except for Windows 8 x64. On this version it takes the application 10 secs to get from the application me.startup event to immediately before InitializeComponents, as can be see from the below time-stamps. None of my code sits inbetween these events.

- 25/05/2013 6:29:02 PM: MyApplication_Startup
- 25/05/2013 6:29:12 PM: InitializeComponent()
- 25/05/2013 6:29:12 PM: frmmain_Initialise
- 25/05/2013 6:29:12 PM: frmMain_Load
- 25/05/2013 6:29:12 PM: frmMain_Shown

On all other versions of Windows its taking 1.5 secs. Ive noticed that during the 10 seconds the app is using 50% of cpu. Ive also built a test app using the same form components to see if there was a problem specific to my VS config but that app ran fine. In my research, Ive found a few issues which are similar but none that are the same. Ive tested this on fresh installs of Windows 8 with the same results each time. Ive also tried running the "framework64\v4\ngen update" fix that was an issue raised previously but still no luck. I'm curious to know if anyone else has come across this or may have any ideas as to what might be the cause? Many thanks.

Comment: If another application that uses the same components as yours *works*, then the problem is with your application. The thing to start doing is ripping chunks out of your app and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Only the base Form constructor and the initialization of any members of your own form sits in between.  Of course you should check this on a do-nothing form first.  If that's greatly delayed as well then the .NET framework install is borked with missing native images.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Ive tested pulling different bits and pieces out without success but ill keep at it. Ive reverted to x86 for the time being.

Comment: Did you solve this ? I'm facing similar issue. Can you tell me how did you proceed? Thanks